# Spring boot2 complains about CircuitBreakerConfigurationOnMissingBean

Tags: java, java-8, resilience4j, spring-boot-2

I've spring boot application running on spring boot version 2.0.6. I added resilience4j to have circuit breaker feature, but application complains about CircuitBreakerConfigurationOnMissingBean.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [io.github.resilience4j.circuitbreaker.autoconfigure.CircuitBreakerConfigurationOnMissingBean] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@1b9e1916
```

Tried added all the required dependencies. POM snippet

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>resilience4j-spring-boot2</artifactId>
            <version>0.17.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>resilience4j-rxjava2</artifactId>
            <version>0.17.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use spring boot version 2.1.0 because `CircuitBreakerConfigurationOnMissingBean` has a dependency that is only available in version 2.1.0 or above.